# How to solve issue Flutter Daemon failed to start

Tags: flutter

How to resolve this issue. I have followed every step of stackoverflow and youtube how to solve this issue. But still the same. I have changed gradle.properties. I have cleared the cache from the folder vs code. But still the same. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.And one more things I can run any command in terminal and cmd. Example when i I run flutter doctor command just show was unexpected at this time.

[image]

[image]

```
Dart Code extension: 3.39.20220411
Flutter extension: 3.38.1 (not activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.66.2
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.17.0-182.2.beta
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\Flutter\flutter
    Ver: 2.12.0-4.2.pre

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[6:04:44 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] Spawning C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat with args ["daemon"]
[6:04:44 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  in C:\Flutter\flutter
[6:04:44 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[6:04:45 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info]     PID: 8948
[6:04:45 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ==> [{"id":"1","method":"emulator.getEmulators"}]
[6:04:45 PM] [General] [Info] Spawning C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["devtools","--machine","--try-ports","10","--allow-embedding"]
[6:04:45 PM] [General] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[6:04:45 PM] [General] [Info]     PID: 8948
[6:04:45 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] Spawning C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["language-server","--client-id=VS-Code","--client-version=3.39.20220411"]
[6:04:45 PM] [Analyzer] [Info]     PID: 1468
[6:04:45 PM] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
[6:04:45 PM] [General] [Info] Extension:Startup timing: 1471ms
[6:04:45 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 4913
[6:04:45 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":8948,"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code","version":"1.66.2"},"locale":"en-us","rootPath":"d:\\doc_portal_upgrade_staging","rootUri":"file:///d%3A/doc_portal_upgrade_staging","capabilities":{"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"workspaceEdit":{"documentChanges":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"],"failureHandling":"textOnlyTransactional","normalizesLineEndings":true,"changeAnnotationSupport":{"groupsOnLabel…
[6:04:46 PM] [General] [Info] !! PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING !!

Dart Code extension: 3.39.20220411
Flutter extension: 3.38.1 (activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.66.2
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.17.0-182.2.beta
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\Flutter\flutter
    Ver: 2.12.0-4.2.pre

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[6:04:46 PM] [General] [Info] Caching Pub package names from pub.dev...
[6:04:46 PM] [General] [Info] <== {"event":"server.started","method":"server.started","params":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":9100,"pid":14460,"protocolVersion":"1.1.0"}}
[6:04:47 PM] [General] [Info] Found 0 folders requiring "pub get":
[6:04:55 PM] [Analyzer] [Info] <== Content-Length: 409
Content-Type: application/vscode-jsonrpc; charset=utf-8

{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"capabilities":{"executeCommandProvider":{"commands":["edit.sortMembers","edit.organizeImports","edit.fixAll","edit.sendWorkspaceEdit","refactor.perform"],"workDoneProgress":true},"workspaceSymbolProvider":true,"workspace":{"workspaceFolders":{"supported":true,"changeNotifications":true}}},"serverInfo":{"name":"Dart SDK LSP Analysis Server","version":"2.17.0-182.2.beta"}}}
[6:04:55 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Error] Checking Dart SDK version... 
<< was unexpected at this time.
```